# Qt check file signature validity

Tags: c++, qt, signed, gnupg

I have a data file, a signature file (created by the GnuPG) and a public key.

I need to check the validity of the signed file. What's the best way to do this with Qt? I've found the [Qt Cryptographic Architecture](http://delta.affinix.com/qca/), but can't find any examples for my task. Can QCA do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always best not to write crypto yourself. can you write a wrapper around calls to gnupg and just execute `gpg --verify pub.key file`?

Having said that, it looks qca has done some of this work, see qca_securemessage.h, you presumeably want to call `void startVerify(const QByteArray &detachedSig = QByteArray());`